# Divide two long vars then subtract gives zero

Tags: java, class, long-integer

Dears,

I have a tiny issue in my Java code. Code should divide two long numbers (this works fine). When subtracting from the result it gives zero while it should give an other result!

The code is about getting number of years and days in a given  number of minutes.

```html
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestMinsToYearsDays {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  MinsToYearsDays minsToYearsDays = new MinsToYearsDays();
  
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  
  System.out.print("Enter the number of Minutes: ");
  minsToYearsDays.miniute = sc.nextLong();
  
  long years;
  years = minsToYearsDays.miniute / 525600L;
  
  long remaining;
  remaining = ((  years-(minsToYearsDays.miniute / 525600L) ) * 365L);
  
  System.out.println("\n Minutes are approximatly " + years + " years and " + remaining + " days " + minsToYearsDays.miniute);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
years = minsToYearsDays.miniute / 525600L;
```

means that

```
years-(minsToYearsDays.miniute / 525600L) == 0
```

Therefore

```
remaining = ((years-(minsToYearsDays.miniute / 525600L)) * 365L);
```

is 0.

You got your formula wrong. If you want to compute the remaining minutes (after subtracting the whole years), it should be:

```
remainingMinutes = minsToYearsDays.miniute - years * 525600L;
```

If you want to compute the number of remaining whole days, it should be:

```
remainingDays = (minsToYearsDays.miniute - years * 525600L) / 1440;
```

Comment: calculating years is fine. the issue in calculating number of days (i.e., calculating the remaining days). as an example, if the scanner get the input 1000000000 the number of years is 1902 and remaining days is 214. the code calculates the number of years correctly but gives zero in the remaining number of days. i think the issue is type casting but i was not able to fix it.

Comment: @OmarAlamoudi I never said calculating years was wrong.

Comment: Yes it was type casting. Your reply was helpful. thanks